# jquery ui accordion not working on a dynamically added tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to add the accordion to a dynamically added tab. This tab is generated by the post back data from the server. What should I do on this?

The post back data is something like

```
<div id ="newtab">
<div id = "accordion"> ...</div>
...
</div>
```

I have

```
$("#accordion1).accordion();
```

before the tab is added, but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you've already identified the problem in the question:

> `$("#accordion1).accordion();`
>
> **before the tab is added**, but it is not working.

You need to initialize the accordion again after the new elements are added to the DOM (i.e. in the `success` function of your AJAX call).

Your jQuery selector `$("#accordion")`, is only selecting elements that are currently in the document. You could use a plugin like [`.livequery`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) to call the function you want automatically on new elements.

---

If you're not opposed to using the livequery plugin mentioned above, here's an example:

```
$("#accordion").livequery(function () {
    $(this).accordion();
});
```

This will make any element added to the DOM with the `id` `#accordion` into an accordion.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/HBFnJ/

Comment: so my concern is, is there anyway to do a live on the accordion?

Comment: @Seen: Using the plugin, there sure is! I'll add an example in case that's a route you'd like to take.

Comment: Thanks! I would try that now!

Comment: It works...I tried to Google for similar questions before and I think your solution is neat and handy.Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for a solution to a similar problem when I came across this post. But here you would have to import a plugin.
I tried another option and it worked for me.

when dynamic data is added then call the destroy method of the accordion. like this:

```
.accordion( "destroy" );
```

and initialize the accordion again with the same options, you applied on the div earlier :)

Comment: THANK YOU! This seems to work better than any solution I've found. It still feels a little buggy on a second .accordion() instance though. Also, any way to check if an element has been accordioned before? (I just put the "destroy" command in a try/catch before .accordion()